# Key fob programming

Tags: dodge

I have a 2013 Dodge Ram 1500. Since the day I bought it, both of my key fobs only unlock the passenger doors. I've had to use my key to manually unlock driver's door. How can I program the fobs to unlock my driver door?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the driver's side door lock and unlock using the interior buttons?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no programming that allows for the fob to only unlock the passenger door or programming that would allow you to activate the unlock feature for the drivers door. You are having a malfunction somewhere in your trucks electronics or wiring**

Side note: This is most likely a problem with the controlling module. If your ram still uses the TIPM7 style module then its probably the relay for the drivers door unlock.